# primefaces openDialog issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on primeface, Dialog framework.

but there are no such methods like `openDialog` or `closeDialog`.

I'm using:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewCars", options, null);
```

but there is no such method. I am using latest library of primefaces, i.e., 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way i did

```
  RequestContext context2 = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context2.execute("PF('opendialog').show()");
```

remember that `opendialog` is the `widgetVar` 
in `xhtml` it should be like

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Open Dialog Box" widgetVar="opendialog">
```

I have used this and its working.

Comment: `opendialog.show()` syntax is deprecated, use `PF('opendialog').show()`

Comment: that is correct, i have use the method you provided forgot to mention it here thanks for notifying

Comment: Above Example is for external page, and you give the solution of internal p:dialog on page

Answer (score 0):

primefaces RequestContext as mentioned by anas, can execute javascript from the backend. If that is what you need, that hould be an optimal solution, but, if you have to open a dialog uppon a button click or process, you could use the buttons events.

```
<p:commandButton value="Open dialog" actionListener="anyMethod" onsuccess="dialog.show();"/>
<p:commandButton value="Close dialog" actionListener="anyMethod" onsuccess="dialog.hide();"/>
```

You could use onsuccess or oncomplete, that goes according to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually there is such method. (in 4.0)**

Check you have imported correct RequestContext class

`import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;`

There are plenty of RequestContext classes from other libraries and you might mistakenly choose wrong one using autocomplete feature of an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following configurations to the "faces-config.xml" file:

```
<action-listener>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
</action-listener>
<navigation-handler>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
</navigation-handler>
<view-handler>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
</view-handler>
```

This part is documented in the ver.5.0 of primeface, but not mentioned in primeface 4.0

It works for me. (glassfish 3.0+primeface 4.0)